# Can a userscript delete cookies from a given domain?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, greasemonkey, userscripts

Can Greasemonkey delete cookies from a given domain? If so, how?

Comment: In Firefox you can already delete cookies from whichever domain you want, as well as blocking cookies from a specific domain.  You can find this in the "Options..." dialog.  Is there a particular reason you want a Greasemonkey script for this?

Comment: I want to automate it for a site that I need to clear cookies from repeatedly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are major limitations on what Greasemonkey can delete. Other tools may be better for what you want, see below.  But, if all of these conditions are met:

- The cookies you want to delete are on the current page's domain.
- They are not ["Secure cookies"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly).
- You loop through the possible paths, including `/`, a blank path, etc.
- No cookies are set by javascript, after the page loads.
- The thing tracking you really is a "cookie".  Many websites use a variety of other techniques, including LSO's, local storage, etc.

*THEN*, the following code will delete them:

```js
//--- Loop through cookies and delete them.
var cookieList  = document.cookie.split (/;\s*/);

for (var J = cookieList.length - 1;   J >= 0;  --J) {
    var cookieName = cookieList[J].replace (/\s*(\w+)=.+$/, "$1");

    eraseCookie (cookieName);
}
```

Where `eraseCookie()` is:
(Note that this *eraseCookie* gets many more cookies by attempting all possible paths and the most likely sub-domains.)

```
function eraseCookie (cookieName) {
    //--- ONE-TIME INITS:
    //--- Set possible domains. Omits some rare edge cases.?.
    var domain      = document.domain;
    var domain2     = document.domain.replace (/^www\./, "");
    var domain3     = document.domain.replace (/^(\w+\.)+?(\w+\.\w+)$/, "$2");;

    //--- Get possible paths for the current page:
    var pathNodes   = location.pathname.split ("/").map ( function (pathWord) {
        return '/' + pathWord;
    } );
    var cookPaths   = [""].concat (pathNodes.map ( function (pathNode) {
        if (this.pathStr) {
            this.pathStr += pathNode;
        }
        else {
            this.pathStr = "; path=";
            return (this.pathStr + pathNode);
        }
        return (this.pathStr);
    } ) );

    ( eraseCookie = function (cookieName) {
        //--- For each path, attempt to delete the cookie.
        cookPaths.forEach ( function (pathStr) {
            //--- To delete a cookie, set its expiration date to a past value.
            var diagStr     = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
            document.cookie = diagStr;

            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; domain=" + domain  + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; domain=" + domain2 + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; domain=" + domain3 + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
        } );
    } ) (cookieName);
}
```

Optional function, for information or debug:

```
function listCookies () {
    var cookieList  = document.cookie.split (/;\s*/);

    for (var J = 0, numCookies = cookieList.length;   J < numCookies;  ++J) {
        console.log ("Cookie ", J, ": ", cookieList[J]);
    }
}
```

---

Your GM script can also use iFrame tricks to delete cookies on third-party domains, but GM is not the best way to handle cookies, in general.

Don't be fooled by any other claims, Greasemonkey and javascript simply cannot delete a cookie unless all of the conditions, listed at the top of this answer, are met.  Note that javascript and Greasemonkey cannot even ***see*** all the cookies on a page.

Greasemonkey is not the best tool for this, although it may be adequate for select situations.

Here are some far more powerful solutions:

1. Use [Selective Cookie Delete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selectivecookiedelete/).  It keeps the cookies you want and deletes the rest.  It does this at the push of a very handy button or automatically when Firefox closes.  Both white-lists and black-lists are supported.
2. Use [BetterPrivacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/betterprivacy/) for sneakier LSO's.
3. Run [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) at least once a week, to exorcise a broad spectrum of tracking and cruft.
4. For powerful, custom, fully-automated cookie removal that does not have the severe limitations that Greasemonkey has, and that runs more often than *Selective Cookie Delete*, you can write your own browser extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally a cookie deletion script that works!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete cookies for the currently open site.  Have a look at the [Cookie Zapper script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/68231), this may do what you want and if not the source will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: HTTP-only cookies cannot be deleted using that method (in Greasemonkey).